# Why doesn't the add to windows startup function work?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, registry

In task manager autorun disabled status.
Where is the error in this function?

```
void AutoRun()
{
    char arr[MAX_PATH] = { };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPWSTR)arr, MAX_PATH);
    
    HKEY hKey;

    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"svchost", NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)arr, (sizeof(arr) + 1)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

**Task manager:**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly compiling for Unicode, but you are using a `char[]` array instead of a `wchar_t[]` array.  You need to use the latter.

You are also passing the wrong length value to `RegSetValueEx()`. You need to specify the byte length of the string only up to, and including, the null terminator.  Not the byte length of the entire array as a whole (in fact, you are specifying even more than that).

Also, you are leaking the `HKEY` if `RegSetValueEx()` fails.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void AutoRun()
{
    wchar_t arr[MAX_PATH] = { };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, arr, MAX_PATH);
    
    HKEY hKey;

    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, NULL, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"svchost", NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)arr, (lstrlen(arr)+1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
}
```